# how to create a Doxygen link to the same file

Tags: doxygen

I would like to write a Doxygen comment that names the file in which the comment occurs. Rather than write the filename explicitly, I would like Doxygen to supply me with it. Thus, if I change the name of the file, or move some of the content into a different file, I don't need to change hard-coded instances of the name.

For a concrete example, let's say I'm adding comments to functions in array.hpp, and I want the comment for certain functions to say "This function should only be used within array.hpp." I want to be able to write

```
/**
 *  This function should only be used within @thisfile.
 */
```

where `@thisfile` is a Doxygen expression that translates into `array.hpp` within the file `array.hpp`.

I've looked at the Doxygen documentation, including "Automatic link generation/Links to files" and the entire "Special Commands" section, but I haven't found what I'm looking for. Does such functionality exist?

Note that essentially the same question was asked on the Doxygen mailing list a few weeks ago. It has not received any replies.

Answer (score 1):

## General

As far as I know such functionality does not exist out-of-the-box. But you can add it by configuring an [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) in your `Doxyfile`. The path to the file is passed as an argument to the filter by doxygen. This can be used by the filter to replace your keyword (for example `@thisfile`) with the path to the file.

Below I give an example how to implement this with `bash`. A solution for other shells or Windows should be quite similar.

## Example for `bash`

1. Write a short `bash` script `infiltrate_filename.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   pathToScript=`pwd`"/"
   sed -e "s:@thisfile:${1/$pathToScript/}:g" $1
   ```

   This script truncates the path to the file by the working directory. The resulting string is used to replace the keyword of your choice (here: `@thisfile`).
2. Make your script executable: `chmod +x infiltrate_filename.sh`
3. Set the [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) in your `Doxyfile` to `INPUT_FILTER = ./infiltrate_filename.sh`

That's it!  Now you can use `@thisfile` in your [documentation blocks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock) and it will be replaced by the path to the file. As the paths are relative to Doxygen's working directory they will [automatically be linked](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html#linkfile) to the file.

### Notes

This solution assumes that the filter script is located in the working directory of doxygen (for example `~/my_project`) and that the [`INPUT`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input) files are in subdirectories of the working directory (for example `~/my_project/src/foo/bar`).

I have tested this example on a minimum working example. I am not a `bash` or `sed` expert. This solution may be improvable.