# Doxygen: extract specific doxygen defines into separate documentaion

Tags: doxygen

I have some source code (STM32 Peripherial Lib) with existing doxygen parameters which my Doxygen Builds without Problems.

For my project I want to generate a document with all functions in each file and a specific information which I want to add to the functions. But I want to keep the old informations for another doxygen configuration.

Is that possible?

I already added this for testing:

`\ifnot "SECTION_DEFINE"
     <normal Doxygen Parameters from original Source Code>
\elsif "SECTION_DEFINE"
     @brief Function Check TODO
\endif`

With this I could deactivate the existing documentation, but I need to write this \ifnot \elsif \endif to every function.
Can I just declare a Tag and only generate the documentation for this specific tag?

Kind regards
Andi

Comment: did you have a look at the ALIASES in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a "related page" where only your additional information will be displayed with the [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) command. As `\xrefitem` will also create a special text section within your original documentation you may want to combine it with your original idea of using section labels and [conditional documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enabled_sections). To top this concept off, use [aliases](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) in order to make your documentation more readable.

Consider this example code:

```
/** ST documentation
 * foobar
 * \exclusive for andi's function \endif
 */
void andreas(void);

/** ST documentation
 * foobar
 * \exclusive for beni's function \endif
 */
void benjamin(void);
```

You may use this alias in your Doxyfile: `exclusive=\if SECTION_DEFINE \xrefitem viparea "Exclusive" "VIPs"`.

As long as `SECTION_DEFINE` is not defined, the "exclusive" information will not be included in your documentation. As soon as this section is defined, a "related page" (*here: `viparea.html`*) is created in your [HTML documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_generate_html) containing your documented items (*here: `andreas` and `benjamin`*) with the exclusive paragraph behind the command. The result:

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. It is very helpful. I've added an Alias and added a line into my source code documentaion. But I've an other question. Can I add the actual filename into my alias or the source code documentation? I tried several things but I cannot get the filename into this.

Comment: I am glad I could help you @duderino65! I am not sure if I can answer your second question (the one in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322405/doxygen-extract-specific-doxygen-defines-into-separate-documentaion/49324306?noredirect=1#comment85731162_49324306)), but I will look into that. You should consider to [formally ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as this will more likely get attention from other community members than your comment alone.

Comment: @duderino65, it seems to be that your second question (the one in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322405/doxygen-extract-specific-doxygen-defines-into-separate-documentaion/49324306?noredirect=1#comment85731162_49324306)) has already been [asked](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/placing-the-filename-in-the-documentation-tp7665.html) on the Doxygen mailing list and later even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38513580/5534993) on SO. The latter asks for a link to the file, but I guess the result should be satisfactory. Unfortunately both have not been answered yet.

Comment: @duderino65: I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373325/5534993) to your second question (the one in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322405/doxygen-extract-specific-doxygen-defines-into-separate-documentaion/49324306#comment85731162_49324306)).

Comment: thanks again for your help. This works fine for me. I set it up on my Linux Buildserver and Jenkins. I can pull out the actual html file which I generate with this topic. On Windows this script is working when it gets called by mintty.exe (git bash from Git For Windows). But when I start make on Windows it is not working. One thing is the "./" in INPUT_FILTER = ./filter.sh and there also is some other Problem I don't get now. But this is a good solution for me to build this extra documentation on jenkins.

Thanks and kind regards Andi